# ListView in nativescript-vue slow to scroll

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

The listview is so slow when scrolling. It hits the bottom and bounces like it has run out of items to display. If you retry, it lets you scroll further. The same thing happens on the way back up the list.

I load in my array of only 40 items using a vuex getter.

```
computed: {
    history () {
        return this.$store.getters.allHistory;
    }
},
```

Then the ListView is simply

```
<ListView ref="listView" for="item in history">
    <v-template>
        <StackLayout height="60" padding="10">
            <Label :text="item.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>/>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You have an error there at `</StackLayout>/>`. Also, try removing the `textWrap='true'` to test. It should work though. I have a `<ListView>` with hundreds of variable height elements that work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, but no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the fixed height and padding seemed to fix. This is working...

```
<ListView ref="listView" for="item in history">
    <v-template>
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*" rows="auto, auto" margin="10">
            <Image v-show="item.poster_url.length > 0" :src="item.poster_url" marginRight="5"
                   stretch="aspectFill" height="100" borderRadius="5"></Image>
            <StackLayout col="1" row="0" rowSpan="2">
                <Label :text="item.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```